# (HTML/JavaScript) Display Serialize Data to Another HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display my serialize data from a table input to another HTML page. What I currently have is displaying the serialize data to an alert from JavaScript.

HTML file code block

```
<form id="form">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Race</th>
                <th>Equity Partners</th>
                <th>Non-Equity Partners</th>
                <th>Associates</th>
                <th>Counsel</th>
                <th>Other Lawyers</th>
                <th>Totals</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


            <tr>

                <td><label>American Indian/Alaska Native</label></td>

                <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_EP" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

                <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_NEP" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

                <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_A" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

                <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian1_C" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

                <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_OL" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

                <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_T" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

            </tr>
```

JavaScript file code block

```
$("#btn-ser1").click(function(){
  data_array = $("#form").serialize();

  alert(data_array);
```

Comment: You can't just have JavaScript data from one page show up on another. One option would be to  to `POST` the data with `AJAX` to a database via a server-side scripting page, and then retrieve it from the database on the output page. Another option would be to store the data in a `cookie` or `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have access to server-based scripting you can use PHP/ASP or another serverside scripting language to post and print the `data_array`.

PHP example:

page 2

```
 <script>
 data = <? if (isset($_POST['data_page1'])){ echo $_POST['data_page1'];}else{echo "null";}>?;
 </script>
```

If not, I would recommend [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this. And converting to JSON and not using serialize.

Since the snippet will throw an error with localstorage, here's a fiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/gutw9o6s/

```js
//page 1
$("#btn-ser1").click(function() {
  data_array = $("#form >input").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  });


  localStorage.setItem('data_page1', JSON.stringify(data_array));
});

//page 2
$("#btn-ser2").click(function() {
  if (localStorage.key('data_page1')) {
    data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data_page1'));
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
          <th>Race</th>
          <th>Equity Partners</th>
          <th>Non-Equity Partners</th>
          <th>Associates</th>
          <th>Counsel</th>
          <th>Other Lawyers</th>
          <th>Totals</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


        <tr>

          <td><label>American Indian/Alaska Native</label></td>

          <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_EP" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

          <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_NEP" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

          <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_A" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

          <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian1_C" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

          <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_OL" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

          <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="AmericanIndian_T" value="" placeholder="Enter Value Here" /></td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
<button id="btn-ser1">Set page 1</button>
<button id="btn-ser2">Get page 2</button>
```

> remember to delete the localStorage after somebody comes to page two with success, because otherwise localStorage will hold on to the values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Mouser. I would just like to stick with HTML and JavaScript for the exercise I'm doing. Should I deserialize my "data_array" before storing it in a localstorage?

Comment: Thank you @Mouser. I just saw your edit. How do I access the serialize data? Do I just set it in an HTML value?

Comment: Well I would recommend JSON for this, see the update

Comment: How do I call/display the serialize data on a table form once I have successfully used localstorage on page 1 and 2?

Comment: Look at the example. It uses JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.